# Drawing Dice in a Windows C++ program?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi

We just started learning windows programming in C++. We have to make a program that has 4 die on the screen, and when the user presses 'SpaceBar', the die roll, or the number of dots on the die change randomly.  Our professor hasent given us a lot of information, so I am kind of just looking for some direction.

Right now, I have 4 squares drawn on the screen, made with the Rectangle() function.

```
Rectangle(hDC,30,100,130,200);
Rectangle(hDC,180,100,280,200);
Rectangle(hDC,330,100,430,200); 
Rectangle(hDC,480,100,580,200);
```

My question is 1) how would I go about drawing dots on these 'squares' and not on the 'screen'.  So if I move the die upwards, the dots move with the square and dont just stay stationed painted on the screen.  And 2.) How would I go about making those dots randomly change when spacebar is pressed (simulating that they have been rolled)?
Just looking for some direction, thanks.

Comment: So it looks like you're using raw GDI calls above. the rest of them are documented here. Since its homework, look for a way to draw a filled circle or ellipse here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927613.aspx   (Ie, the dots on the dice are usually filled circles).

Comment: What exactly is the required animation for the dice being rolled? When you say "move the die upwards", do you mean just vertically, or actually turning it into the screen as well?

Comment: @chris The die are just guna move horizontally and vertically around the screen. Pretty simple, I can make the squares move, but Im pretty sure the dots wont, and they will just stay wherever I painted them on the screen.

Comment: Got it. I was thinking that rotating the dice into the screen would be a bit extreme without the aid of Direct3D or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)
You will still have to draw them on the screen, but you can structure your program to realize the dots as part of the square.

```
void moveSquare()
{
    //change square position
    //change dots positions the same as you changed the square
}
```

---

2)
You can capture keypresses in your window with the `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` messages, or the `WM_CHAR` message. Just start a chain of changing how many dots are supposed to appear on the die when space is pressed (`SetTimer` could be handy), and let `WM_PAINT` do the work of painting the dots (or call something to calculate the positions of the dots, and let `WM_PAINT` loop through each dot it needs to draw.

```
void OnSpacePressed()
{
    //start changing dots every so often, handled elsewhere
    //maybe check if finished rolling before doing so
}

void calculateDotPositions()
{
    switch (numberOfDots) {...} //hint: use the square as a reference point
}

void OnPaint()
{ 
    //paint each sqaure
    //paint each dot in the correct position, which should be updated with square
}

void OnChangeDots()
{
    //change number of dots
    //also start a new change to happen later if not done rolling
}
```

For drawing dots, use Warren P's reference link.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is to create a bitmap or picture in memory.  One for each of the 6 faces of the die.  The objective here is to copy the bitmaps to the screen, rather than having to redraw them each time.  Research "bitmap", and "bitblt".

Comment: That definitely is one solution, and good practice for later. I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a routine that draws a die at the origin, offset by given coordinates. I'm not familiar with the particular library you are using, so I don't know what hDC is, but it should look something like the following.

```
void drawDie(HDC hDC, int xCoord, int yCoord, int dieValue)
{
    Rectangle(hDC, -50 + xCoord, -50 + yCoord, 50 + xCoord, 50 + yCoord);

    // draw some number of circles specified by dieValue at appropriate coordinates
    // translated by xCoord and yCoord arguments
}
```

Then you can just redraw dice over your previous ones if you want them to change.

Comment: HDC is a handle to a device context. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa921543.aspx

Comment: Put into elementary terms, it's a canvas. Each window has one, so it needs to know which to draw on.